# Fourier Transform Inequality

Tags: fourier-transform

I am trying to find conditions that the real-valued function $f$ should satisfy in order to guarantee an inequality of the form:
$$
\left| \mathcal{F} f (\lambda) \right| \leq |g(\lambda)|.
$$
Here $\mathcal{F}f$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f$:
$$
\mathcal{F}f(\lambda) = \int e^{- i \lambda x} f(x) dx.
$$

Comment: What does g denote?

Comment: $g$ is another real-valued function.

Comment: Are you given g and trying to find f, or are you trying to find an f such that there exists a g for which this works?

Comment: I think you cannot arbitrarily give $f$ or $g$, today there exists nothing sharper than (generalised) Paley-Wiener theory on that matter.

Comment: I know $g$, and was trying to find suitable $f$'s which would satisfy the inequality. I am still going over the Paley-Wiener theory that you suggested. Thank you for your answer @mol3574710n0fN074710n !

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Paley-Wiener theorem:
$f$ is a (complex valued) $L^2$-function with $\mathtt{supp}f=\left[-A,A\right]$

if and only if for $\bar{f}\left(\xi\right)\;:=\;\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(x\right)\cdot e^{ix \xi}\mathtt{d}x,\;\xi\in\mathbb{C}$ the following hold:

i) $\left|\bar{f}\right|$ is an entire function.

ii) $\exists C\;\forall\xi\in\mathbb{C}\;:\;\left|\bar{f}\left(\xi\right)\right|\leq e^{A\cdot\left|\xi\right|}$ ("$\bar{f}$ is of exponential type $A$").

iii) $\forall y\in\mathbb{R}\;:\;\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|\bar{f}\left(x+i\cdot y\right)\right|^{2}\mathtt{d}x<\infty$

Note that the growth constant $A$ yields a sharp estimate for the support and vice versa: Among the functions $f$ with the property that the magnitude of the (inverse) FT $\bar{f}$ is a function of exponential type $A$ there are always some with a support that spans the whole interval $\mathtt{supp}f=\left[-A,A\right]$ and conversely if $\mathtt{supp}f=\left[-A,A\right]$ the inverse FT will be of exponential type $A$.

There is a multitude of Paley-Wiener theorems, they form a whole class of theorems relating the growth of a complex function to the support of its fourier transform. Google is your friend here, good luck finding one that fits your needs!

EDIT:

For real $f$ also this simple relationship may help (you probably already know it):
$$\left|\hat{f}\left(\omega\right)\right|^{2}=\hat{f}\left(\omega\right)\cdot\overline{\hat{f}\left(\omega\right)}\underset{f\mathrm{\; real}}{=}\hat{f}\left(\omega\right)\cdot\hat{f}\left(-\omega\right)=\mathcal{F}\left(\left(f\left(\cdot\right)*f\left(-\cdot\right)\right)\left(t\right)\right)=\mathcal{F}\left(\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(\xi\right)*f\left(\xi-t\right)\mathtt{d}\xi\right)
 $$
Assuming the integral exists. -- The keywords here are "autocorrelation" and "energy spectral density".

Also note Plancharel's theorem ($f$ may be complex-valued again): $$\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|\hat{f}\left(\omega\right)\right|^{2}\mathtt{d}\omega=\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|f\left(t\right)\right|^{2}\mathtt{d}t
 $$

Assuming the integrals exist.

Finally, here is a question of mine with respect to Paley-Wiener. This question (and my own answer) contain some additional formulae, that you may look at - maybe it is useful...:
[Designing a FIR filter in frequency domain: Paley-Wiener "the other way around".](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2761892/designing-a-fir-filter-in-frequency-domain-paley-wiener-the-other-way-around)